# Migrate legacy database to cqrs/event sourcing view

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

We got old legacy application with complex business logic which we need to rewrite. We consider to use cqrs and event sourcing. But it's not clear how to migrate data from the old database. Probable we need migrate it to the read database only, as we can't reproduce all the events to populate event store. But we atleast need to create some initial records in event store for each aggregate, like `AggregateCreated`? Or we need write a scripts and to use all the commands one by one to recreate aggregates in same way we will normally with event sourcing?

Answer (score 6):

Using the existing database, or a transformed version of it, as a start of your read-side persistence is never a good idea. Your event-sourced system needs to have its start, so you get one of the main benefits of event sourcing - being able to create projections on-demand, using polyglot persistence.

Using commands for migration is also not a good idea for a simple reason that commands, by definition, can fail due to pre or post-condition check of invariant control. It also does not convey the meaning of migration, which is to represent the current system state as it is right now. Remember, that the current system stay is not something you can accept or deny. It is given to you and your job is to capture it.

The best practice for such a migration is to emit so-called migration events, like `EntityXMigratedFromLegacy`. Of course, the work might be substantial. Mainly because the legacy system model will most probably not match the new model, otherwise the reason for such a migration isn't entirely clear.

By using migration events you explicitly state the fact that a piece of state was moved from another place, as-is. You will always know how the migrated entity started its lifecycle in the new system - either by being migrated from legacy or by being initialised in the new system.

Answer (score 0):

> Probable we need migrate it to the read database only

No, your read model db can be dropped and recreated any time based on write side, only write side is your source of truth.

> But we atleast need to create some initial records in event store for
>   each aggregate, like AggregateCreated?

Of course, and having ONLY the initial event could be not enough. If your current OrderAggregate has reservations, you must create ItemReservedEvent for-each reservation it has.

> Or we need write a scripts and to use all the commands one by one to
>   recreate aggregates in same way we will normally with event sourcing?

Feels like that's the way you should go. Read old aggregate/entity from db and try to map it to a new one.