# How to migrate to Event-Sourcing?

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

we are migrating from a legacy monolith application to a microservice architecture. we use CQRS and event sourcing pattern and message broker (rabbitmq) for communication mechanism. now We are facing a challenge about how can convert the old database to new architecture and how can use event sourcing for these? Assuming the old database did not have events, can we do the data conversion without creating events? what is the start point of our old database data in the event sourcing pattern?

Answer (score 1):

One important thing to remember is that many databases internally event source: every write goes to a log and that log is used to update tables, replicate etc., after which the log is truncated.  It's equivalent to event sourcing with a lot of snapshots and very little retention of events and old snapshots.

In these databases (which include the likes of Postgres, MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, Cassandra, CosmosDB, to name ones I know from experience do this), there's a technique called Change Data Capture which essentially taps into the log and exposes a stream of changes to the database which can be treated as events from the database (or by extension as commands: "one service's events are another service's commands").  Debezium can be used to write CDC records to Kafka; for RabbitMQ you may need to roll something yourself, in which case you'll want to get acquainted with how CDC is exposed in your database.

Even if the database doesn't support CDC, if the data isn't that large, you can often turn it into an ersatz event stream by periodically dumping its data (if the records are timestamped, this can even work if the data is particularly slow moving) and implementing a service to track what changed: this won't tell you about changes that netted out, but it's often better than nothing.  This sort of dump is also likely to be required if you need a "genesis" event to ensure that your initial state is current to when you moved to event-sourcing or CDC.

This whole broad family of techniques has limitations compared to full event sourcing: reifying what changed is not as valuable as reifying what changed and why it changed.  But it can be a useful middle ground in migrating to event-sourcing.

Answer (score 0):

By referring [@alexey-zimarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/484041/alexey-zimarev)'s answer at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60249012/migrate-legacy-database-to-cqrs-event-sourcing-view), it's essential to have the starting event in your event sourced database. You can not configure an event-sourced aggregate without replaying its events. Therefore, you need to map the legacy snapshot to an individual domain event of your relevant aggregate.

Either the way, considering [event souring definition](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) by Martin Fowler:

> The fundamental idea of Event Sourcing is that of ensuring every
> change to the state of an application is captured in an event object,
> and that these event objects are themselves stored in the sequence
> they were applied for the same lifetime as the application state
> itself.

So that, it's not an appropriate solution to migrate legacy snapshots into the newer one without extracting and storing domain events. It will turn your event-sourced project into a semi-event-sourced project which is not considered as a paradigm to design and develop.

Answer (score 0):

You have an event store that is a database for events. you can create event data that you need for the old database and insert into the event store. After that, do event replaying for creating read models.